# Find a matrix of linear transformation A

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a matrix of linear transformation $A\in M_{n\star n}(\mathbb{R})$ and a vector $x\in \mathbb{R}^n $, such that  $x\in Ker(A)$ and $x\in Im(A)$.

---

If $x\in Ker(A)$  then $A\cdot x=0$. And if $x\in Im(A)$ then $\exists y\in \mathbb{R}^n $ such that $A\cdot y=x$.

$\left\{\begin{matrix}
A\cdot x=0\\ 
A\cdot y=x
\end{matrix}\right.$

It's only possible if $A$ is singular. I selected several singular matrices at random, but failed to find proper $x$ and $y$. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1 \\0&0
\\\end{pmatrix}$
and $y=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\1
\\\end{pmatrix}$.

Then $x=Ay=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\0
\\\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Cool! And what about more general solution?

Comment: As you say A must be singular and therefore $A^2$ is singular. Let y be any vector in Ker($A^2$) and x=Ay.